# How to use Regex in Oracle SQL request

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this complex string in a database, which represents 4 elements separated by delimeters '|'

```
1944913|200010|157|4*
1944913|200085|157|1.22*
```

NOTE: both lines of strings exist in the same database row. There could be up to 10 lines of strings in a single cell

I want an oracle sql command that, given either 200010 or 200085, returns either the 1st or second element next to it, like:

Given 200010, returns 157 or returns 4*
Given 200085, returns 157 or returns 1.22

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexp_substr and instr to get the required results:

```
select a.*,
      CASE WHEN instr(text1,'200085')>0 then REGEXP_SUBSTR (substr(text1,instr(text1,'200085'),500),'[^,|]+', 1, 2) 
          ELSE NULL END as partA,
      CASE WHEN instr(text1,'200085')>0 then REGEXP_SUBSTR (substr(text1,instr(text1,'200085'),500),'[^,|]+', 1, 3) 
          ELSE NULL END as partB
from tableA a
```

Simply replace '200085' with the string you are looking for and you should be good to go. Hope this helps.

Comment: this worked! I slightly edited it by adding a replace function in the center to replace the * with a |, which made it work well on multiple rows. Otherwise, perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can split this into columns easily.  So, I think something like this is pretty much what you want:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '[^|]+', 1, 2) as val_2,
       regexp_substr(col, '[^|]+', 1, 3) as val_3,
       regexp_substr(col, '[^|]+', 1, 4) as val_4

from t;
```